# Azure Storage Emulator returns 500 internal server error

Tags: azure

I have an application that uses Azure Storage, when I have reinstalled the Azure Storage Emulator and Explorer and then run the app, I get this error.
The app was working before I reinstalled.

```
[WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.]
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Shared.Protocol.HttpResponseParsers.ProcessExpectedStatusCodeNoException(HttpStatusCode expectedStatusCode, HttpStatusCode actualStatusCode, T retVal, StorageCommandBase`1 cmd, Exception ex) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\Common\Shared\Protocol\HttpResponseParsers.Common.cs:54
   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.<>c__DisplayClass57.<PutBlobImpl>b__56(RESTCommand`1 cmd, HttpWebResponse resp, Exception ex, OperationContext ctx) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Blob\CloudBlockBlob.cs:3132
  Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult getResponseResult) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Executor\Executor.cs:300

[StorageException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.]
   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.StorageAsyncResult`1.End() in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Util\StorageAsyncResult.cs:77
   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.<>c__DisplayClass7.<CreateCallbackVoid>b__5(IAsyncResult ar) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Util\AsyncExtensions.cs:121
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32
   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.AzureStorage.<StoreElementAsync>d__14.MoveNext() +1308
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +62
   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.AzureStorage.AzureBlobXmlRepository.StoreElement(XElement element, String friendlyName) +161
   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager.Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.Internal.IInternalXmlKeyManager.CreateNewKey(Guid keyId, DateTimeOffset creationDate, DateTimeOffset activationDate, DateTimeOffset expirationDate) +1493
   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager.CreateNewKey(DateTimeOffset activationDate, DateTimeOffset expirationDate) +150
   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingProvider.CreateCacheableKeyRingCore(DateTimeOffset now, IKey keyJustAdded) +645
   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingProvider.Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.Internal.ICacheableKeyRingProvider.GetCacheableKeyRing(DateTimeOffset now) +12
   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingProvider.GetCurrentKeyRingCore(DateTime utcNow) +517
   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Protect(Byte[] plaintext) +90
```

Comment: This one worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/70688590/3057246

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal
> Server Error.]

One of the workaround you may follow to resolve the above issue:

- Try to rename the application name with some other name  and restart the azure storage emulator(>run `AzureStorageEmulator.exe start`) and run the application.

Alternatively to  resolve with ***Azure storage explorer*** please find this [***SO THREAD***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70605728/azure-functions-blob-storage-emulator-stopped-working-after-moving-to-vs2022) as suggested by @*Seth*  .

For more information you can refer this [***SO THREAD***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34662226/creating-table-in-azure-storage-emulator-produces-http-500-error#:%7E:text=The%20Error%20500%20seemed%20to,can%27t%20access%20its%20database.) .